# How to put a NSDate Object into sqlite

Tags: sqlite, nsdate

I read some posts about this topic, but nothing solved my problem.
I Have the following lines of code.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Today: %@", today);

self.person.dayOfBirth = today;

NSLog(@"Birth: %@", self.person.dayOfBirth);

[appDelegate saveContext];
```

The NSLog-Statements tell me the right result as expected.
And the Result was also stored in the database.
But when i look at the cell in SQLite Manager, there was a value like this: 399911663.291896
I think its a timestamp cuz the Column's type is "TIMESTAMP"... but the dot is strange.
Now i dont know how to get the right date in my sqlite DB.
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think NSDate is stored in the NSManagedObjects SQLite DB as a NSTimeInterval which is just a double (the seconds since 1970). Do you have problems that the Date is different when you read the objects back out of the DB?

Comment: Core data uses `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to convert the date to a double for the SQLite store. This is the number of seconds since 1 January 2001, GMT.

Comment: yes, it seems to be an NSTimeInterval. When i save the Date, the NSLog-Statements show the right result, but the DB receives it in a wrong way. i think it is converted in a TimeInterval. I changed the DataType of the Column to "DATETIME" but this also doesn't work. So what can be the Solution?

Comment: @user1895268: What are you trying to achieve? Core Data knows how to store a date in the SQLite store and can retrieve it again. Are you trying to access the SQLite file directly? (From your code I assume that you use Core Data, even if you didn't say that.)

Comment: The TimeStamp Column type is correct, but u usually shouldn't create the DB by yourself. You simply create the ManagedObjectModel in XCode and it takes care of everything.

Comment: ok i understood now. But now i know where this crazy numbers come from. thank you very much.